# reducing 2 variables of a function into one

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, interpolation, function

I have an experiment where I'm measuring some physical quantity Q as a function of 3 variables which I can physically control (x,y,z). I'm collecting many samples of Q and (x,y,z) and then I can create an interpolation function given these samples.

One of my coworkers raised the possibility that the function should actually be a 2D function with the variables (x*y,z). In other words, that if I take all of the points with equal x*y and z, the function Q(x,y,z) would have the same value.

I'm looking for a good way to test this assumption and possibly visualize this result.

Comment: If y = f(x) or x = f(z) etc. this might be done. I suggest visual inspections of scatterplots to see if any of these variables might be determined as a function of a different variable. It is worth a quick check just to see if anything obvious turns up.